# Unable to open multiple datepickers integrated with highstock

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, highcharts

I have problems integrating the `datepicker` stuff when working with multiple lines, below is my  prototype in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joe992005/bL5G2/)
I dont see any error here, but it does not work.

Can anybody help me out on here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your jQuery UI version.

Currently you're using **`jQuery v1.9`** and **`jQuery UI v1.8`** and thereby it is suffering from version compatibility.

Change the version of **`jQuery UI to v1.9.2`** and it will work perfectly.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bL5G2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It is related with the fact that in your example you use `jquery 1.9.x` which is not compatible with the jquery UI, which you use. If you downgrade to jquery 1.7.2 it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/bL5G2/2/

Comment: downgrading javascript libraries is not a good options.  Since newer version of libraries are bug fixes or new features of the old one.